# How to get latest revisions for a file list in git?

Tags: git

I would like to get revision numbers for several files (at once if possible), for each file I want to know in which revision it changed last.

Like this:

```
a.txt - a85fb1,
b.txt - 84a146,
c.txt - a85fb1,
...
```

Thx!

Answer (score 3):

This will work for one file at a time:

```
git log --format=%H -1 HEAD a.txt
```

This would work for multiple files "at once":

```
for i in a.txt b.txt c.txt; do paste <(echo $i) <(git log --format=%H -1 HEAD $i); done
```

This might work for all files in your repo:

```
for i in $(git ls-files); do paste <(echo $i) <(git log --format=%H -1 HEAD $i); done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so as I suspected (and other git wizards said), there is no way to get all revisions at once.

Comment: Check my latest edit. It works for all files in my git repository. It might be slow depending on the size of you repository.